# Can't save a cloned record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to provide undo functionality after a record has been deleted. To do this, before I delete the record I clone it and put it in the session like so:

```
session[:undo] ||= []
session[:undo] << record.clone
```

however when I later do

```
rec = session[:undo][-1]
rec.save!
```

The record is not saved. The server console output says

```
(0.2ms)  BEGIN
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
(0.2ms)  COMMIT
```

which makes me think it is saved, but its not in the db. I am very confused. Any ideas?

Comment: A more stable way of doing this is to have an "active" boolean flag in the database that defaults to true. When you delete a record, just change that flag to false. To undo you just change it back to true.

Comment: oh nice. I suppose I have to check this flag every time I access records though? Is there some way to automatically exclude inactive records?

Comment: @providence, You can use `default_scope` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-default_scope) in your model to exclude inactive records.

Comment: thanks. If one of you guys wants to put that up as an answer, I'll accept

Comment: Also, it is best to avoid placing entire records in the session, since they will be marshalled.  Keep in mind that an instance variables (such as cached associations) will be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more stable way of doing this is to have an "active" boolean flag in the database that defaults to true. When you delete a record, just change that flag to false. To undo you just change it back to true.

```
# models/attachment.rb
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(:active => true)

  def self.include_inactive
    unscoped
  end
end

# in your migration
def self.up
  change_table :attachments do |t|
    t.boolean :active, :default => true, :null => false
  end

  add_index :attachments, :active
end
```

The `self.include_inactive` method is really just for clarity. It is really just an alias of `unscoped`, which will reset the `default_scope` that is ignoring deleted records. If you want to, for example, show all records in an admin dashboard, you can call `Attachment.include_inactive`.

Also note the index on the `active` column. Since most queries will include a `where 'active' = 1` it is smart to ensure your database has this information easily accessible.